# How would you select the last two instances of multiple sub-categories in Collection

Tags: c#, linq

Stackoverflow,

Using C# LINQ, how would you select the last two instances of multiple sub-categories in a collection?

In the below code, phaseRepository is a List of Phases.

[image: phaseRepository.Collection]

Each phase has properties which include Direction and Momentum (where Momentum.Undefined should be considered to be the same as Momentum.Time). How would you select the last two instances of phase for the four sub-categories:

- Direction.Up & Momentum.Price
- Direction.Up & Momentum.Time (treating .Time and .Undefined as equal)
- Direction.Down & Momentum.Price
- Direction.Down & Momentum.Time (treating .Time and .Undefined as equal)

The Answer would resemble (order by PhaseNumber is not required):

[image: Answer]

To assist, the below code is a LINQPad C# Program which compiles but is lacking the correct answer:

```
void Main()
{
    var phaseRepository = new PhaseRepository();
    phaseRepository.Collection = GetCollection();

    // answer in its current state is incorrect...
    var answer = phaseRepository.Collection.Select(p => p);

    answer.Dump();  
}

private List<Phase> GetCollection() 
{
    return new List<Phase>
    {
        new Phase ()
        {
            PhaseNumber = 1,
            Direction = Dir.Up,
            Momentum = Mom.Price,
        },
        new Phase ()
        {
            PhaseNumber = 2,
            Direction = Dir.Down,
            Momentum = Mom.Time,
        },
        new Phase ()
        {
            PhaseNumber = 3,
            Direction = Dir.Up,
            Momentum = Mom.Price,
        },
        new Phase ()
        {
            PhaseNumber = 4,
            Direction = Dir.Down,
            Momentum = Mom.Time,
        },
        new Phase ()
        {
            PhaseNumber = 5,
            Direction = Dir.Up,
            Momentum = Mom.Time,
        },
        new Phase ()
        {
            PhaseNumber = 6,
            Direction = Dir.Down,
            Momentum = Mom.Undefined,
        },
        new Phase ()
        {
            PhaseNumber = 7,
            Direction = Dir.Up,
            Momentum = Mom.Price,
        },
        new Phase ()
        {
            PhaseNumber = 8,
            Direction = Dir.Down,
            Momentum = Mom.Price,
        },
        new Phase ()
        {
            PhaseNumber = 9,
            Direction = Dir.Up,
            Momentum = Mom.Price,
        },
        new Phase ()
        {
            PhaseNumber = 10,
            Direction = Dir.Down,
            Momentum = Mom.Time,
        },
        new Phase ()
        {
            PhaseNumber = 11,
            Direction = Dir.Up,
            Momentum = Mom.Time,
        },
        new Phase ()
        {
            PhaseNumber = 12,
            Direction = Dir.Down,
            Momentum = Mom.Undefined,
        }
    };
}

public class PhaseRepository
{
    public List<Phase> Collection = new List<Phase>();
}   

public class Phase
{
    public int PhaseNumber { get; set; }
    public Dir Direction { get; set; }
    public Mom Momentum { get; set; }
}

public enum Dir
{
    Up,
    Down,
    Undefined
}

public enum Mom
{
    Price,
    Time,
    Undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `GroupBy` and `SelectMany` would easily do it:

```
var answer = phaseRepository.Collection
    .OrderBy(p => p.PhaseNumber); // prepare to enforce "last two" requirement
    .GroupBy(p =>
         new { 
            p.Direction, 
            Momentum = p.Momentum == Mom.Undefined ? Mom.Time : p.Momentum
         })
    .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(g.Count() - 2)) // skip all but 2 from each group
    .OrderBy(p => p.PhaseNumber); // optional, to make verification easier
```

The important point here is that `GroupBy` is [guaranteed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534304(v=vs.100).aspx) to preserve inside each group the relative order of elements in the source sequence:

> The IGrouping objects are yielded in an order based on
>   the order of the elements in source that produced the first key of
>   each IGrouping. Elements in a grouping are yielded in
>   the order that the elements that produced them appear in source.

therefore an initial sort by phase number initially is enough to satisfy the "last two in each group" requirement.

Comment: Why not .OrderByDescending + .Take(2)

Comment: @adrianm: No reason, just what came to mind first. I guess I was mechanically translating the idea to code at greater detail level than appropriate. :-)

Answer (score 0):

For Direction.Up & Momentum.Price:

```
phaseRepository.Where(phase =>
{
    phase.Direction == Direction.Up &&
    phase.Momentum == Momentum.Price
}).Reverse().Take(2);
```

You can apply this to all your other needs. If you want undefined to be the same as time you simply check for `phase.Momentum == Momentum.Time || phase.Momentum == Momentum.Undefined`

If you want the last 2 PhaseNumbers, then use `OrderByDescending(x => x.PhaseNumber)` on this number and then `.Take(2)` from it.

If the `Where()` returns less than 2 elements the `Take(2)` will still return an empty list (or 1 element if the `Where()` returns 1 item).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
phaseRepository.Collection
    .GroupBy(x => Tuple.Create(x.Direction, x.Momentum))
    .Where(x => x.Key == //filter on your desired sub catagories
    .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y=>y.PhaseNumber).Take(2).ToList()) //get just the last 2 items
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .OrderBy(y=>PhaseNumber) //return in complete order
```